# Why is the Samsung firmware ISO I downloaded 16MB in size, but when burned to a device it only shows 94KB?

Tags: linux, boot, ssd, firmware, samsung-ssd

I followed [these official instructions from Samsung](https://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/global.semi.static/Firmware_Update_Utility_UserManual.pdf) and downloaded `unetbootin` and the ISO for my Samsung 960 EVO 250GB. I burned it with `unetbootin` and rebooted but there was nothing to boot from.

I did it again and inspected the files on the drive and they were only these files:

```
extlinux.conf
ldlinux.sys
menu.c32
syslinux.cfg
ubnfilel.txt
ubnpathl.txt
```

Which sums up to only 94KB. Also the `unetbootin` record is instantaneous as it if were not recording anything. The firmware ISO has 16MB so the burned SD card should have this size of similar, but it only has those files which sums to 94KB.

How do I update Samsung SSD firmware on Linux?

Comment: Changed the title of the question. There are many questions asking about how to do this, but your issue is very clear: You downloaded an ISO that has 16MB of data bit when you burn it to a device (SD card?) you only see 94KB worth of stuff. That is something someone can see and work with.

Comment: but does it boot?

Comment: @phuclv The original poster clearly states, “…and rebooted but there was nothing to boot from.”

Comment: I downloaded an up-to-date Windows version of UNetbootin (`unetbootin-windows-702.exe`) and it just worked. Maybe the Linux version has a bug?

Answer (score 0):

This is why it is 16MiB:

```
[tom@archlinux ~]$ sudo losetup -P -r -f /tmp/Samsung_SSD_960_EVO_3B7QCXE7.iso
[tom@archlinux ~]$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/loop0
Disk /dev/loop0: 16 MiB, 16777216 bytes, 32768 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x13edd5e6

Device       Boot Start   End Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/loop0p1 *        0 32767   32768  16M 17 Hidden HPFS/NTFS
[tom@archlinux ~]$
```

If you are on Linux, it's probably better to use `dd`, since it's a hybrid ISO that is bootable by itself when written on non-optical storage. Note that you should write it to a disk, not a partition as the PDF has suggested.

Also you'll need CSM and legacy booting for USB drive (assuming you are using a USB card reader) enabled in your UEFI settings.

Comment: I used dd and activated CSM. It boots to a glitchy screen unfortunately